# Slider API of Material is not render the slider properly in case of fraction number as step, marks | material ui | Slider | React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, material-ui

I have a react application on which I am going to add the Material UI slider. But I can't able to create the slider properly. I don't know which property is missing from my side.

Here is my React component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Slider from '@material-ui/core/Slider';

const marks = [
  {
    value: -1.5,
    label: '-1.5'
  },
  {
    value: -0.5,
    label: '-0.5'
  },
  {
    value: 0.5,
    label: '0.5'
  },
  {
    value: 1.5,
    label: '1.5'
  }
];

class SliderUi extends React.Component<any, any> {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
      <Slider
        defaultValue={1.5}
        aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-small-steps"
        step={1.0}
        marks={marks}
        min={-1.5}
        max={1.5}
        valueLabelDisplay="auto"
      />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see that the default value is "1.5" and the step value is 1 so the 1.5 is selected as default.

When the above component is loaded the following output is shown
[image]

and when I slide the Slider then I can't able to select the marked value like 1.5, 0.5 and so on. By default, it is working and I can only select -1, 0 and 1(**But I don't want this. User should only select marked value i.e 1.5, 0.5 and so on**)

[image]

Ref. Link - [Material Slider](https://material-ui.com/components/slider/)

In case someone wants to work on it then [Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-elsd2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay if you want to select the marked value, you should set the step to null
you can do it as

```
return (
  <>
  <Slider
    defaultValue={1.5}
    aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-small-steps"
    step={null}
    marks={marks}
    min={-1.5}
    max={1.5}
    valueLabelDisplay="auto"
  />
  </>
);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: As I mention that I want to select the marked values like 1.5, 0.5, -0.5 and -1.5. that why I set the step value 1 in this case.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-o88h0 this is what you want right ?

Comment: No. As you can see the slider moves on the 1 as well as on 0. I want the user can only select 1.5, 0.5, -0.5 and -1.5 i.e marked value only. See my updated question

Comment: @sachinkumar i got your point, i have updated my answer please check

Comment: Ok. You are right. Can you explain why this happens in the case of set step value 1?

Comment: i think it works well if you have discrete value, but if you don't have a discrete value it floors the value, like 1.5 to 1, https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-o88h0 here you can see the example of 2 and it works as expected

Comment: also you can see https://material-ui.com/api/slider/ the have mentioned it as A "discrete" slider. and if it helped you feel free to up vote the answer cheers